# How to pass self.TableView method to NotificationCenter's addObserver

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do I specify that someController.tableView reloadData is to be called in a notfication?

The implementation of a reload wrapper is:

```
- (void) reloadTableAsContentsHasChanged
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and the call to Notofication center's AddObserver argument is now implemented as:

```
addObserver: self selector: @selector( reloadTableAsContentsHasChanged )
```

It works allright but the wrapper should not be necessary. I have tried several notations but I can't get it right. It should be possible to pass the method reloadData of self.tableView without a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `NSNotificationCenter`'s block-based API.

Assuming that `self` is going to be the object posting this notification...

```
id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserverForName:@"SomeNotificationName"
                object:self
                  queue:nil
             usingBlock: ^(NSNotification *note){[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

and remember to unregister and release `observer` when you don't need to listen for this notification anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.  BTW, the code above needs a closing ']'.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: someController.tableView selector: @selector(reloadData) name: @"someName" object: self];
```

But why don't you just do it like this:

```
[someController.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:tableView selector:@selector(reloadData) name:notificationName object:self];
```

Should work (if it doesn't then Apple might have for some reason made it impossible to notify a `UITableView` directly). Don't forget to remove the tableView from the observers when you release it

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:tableView];
```